# Specifying a class that uses T

Tags: java, android

I'm using a method that takes a `Class<T>` as a parameter.

The class I want to pass as a parameter also uses T.  It is declared as `public class MyObject<T>` and has a member declared as `public T mMyVar;`  I then have 2 classes I sometimes use for `mMyVar` called `MyVarObject1` and `MyVarObject2`.

Example:

```
private class MyObject<T> {
    public T mMyVar;
}

private class MyVarObject1 {
    // some variables
}

private class MyVarObject2 {
    // some variables
}
```

Specifically, the method I'm invoking is the `JacksonUtil` method `fromJsonArray`.

I'm not sure of the proper syntax here.  `JacksonUtil` needs to know the exact model structure so it can parse the json, but I'm having trouble figuring out the proper syntax for this line:

```
MyObject<MyVarObject1> result = JacksonUtil.fromJsonArray(jsonStr, MyObject<MyVarObject1>.class);
```

What I have there doesn't work.  My IDE selects the second parameter and says, "Cannot select from parameterized type."

Comment: `MyObject<MyVarObject1>.class` such a thing does not exist due to type erasure, only `MyObject.class`

Comment: Are you saying there's no way for me to do what I want unless I specify `MyObject<MyVarObject1>` as a parameter in the definition of `JacksonUtil.fromJsonArray` (which I cannot do because it is not my library)?

Comment: Hint: even for more sophisticated folks that have a lot of knowledge; but just start with a new language ... take your time to really **understand** the concept you intent to use. Java generics are somehow an advanced topic; but just the way you are asking implies that you didn't spent much time researching it.

Comment: @Jägermeister agreed, I still struggle with generics at points, and I have been at this for a while :P That being said, yea generics can lead you down an avenue of super messy code if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: I'm not sure which library `JacksonUtil` is from, but Jackson has a `TypeReference` class which solves your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem while using with retrofit, This is my solution -

```
public class ResponseDS<T> {
  public int s;
  public String e;
  public T d;
}
```

And if you need array of object then,

```
public class ResponseDSs<T> {
    public int s;
    public String e;
    public T[] d;
}
```

And below is how I am using it for Retrofit -

```
Call<ResponseDS<UserDS>> userModelCall = ZivaUtils.getRetrofit().getUser();
```

I think you have the same problem, hope my solution will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I do `TypedToken` from Gson to parse custom objects, I think you can find something similar to use with Jackson, i will edit my answer if i find something later.

You may use `TypeToken` to load the json string into a custom object.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
//This is an example, you probably get this from your server as Json String
MyObject<MyObject1>  user = new MyObject<MyObject1>();
String myObjectAsString = gson.toJson(user);
//then parse into your custom object
MyObject other = gson.fromJson(myObjectAsString, new TypeToken<MyObject<MyObject1>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: Yeah, `new TypeToken<ArrayList<User>>(){}.getType());` is how you'd make a list with GSON, for example. It's magic.